# Display Arraylist on jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, liferay

I am trying to display the following ArrayList in the .jsp page shown but I can't seem to see any values once I run my portlet, where is the problem?

code.java

```
 public class TestPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
    public void displayProcess(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {
        ArrayList<String> process = new ArrayList<>();
        process.add("a");
        process.add("b");
        process.add("c");
        process.add("d");
        process.add("e");

        request.setAttribute("processName", process);
    }
}
```

The jsp page is as shown:

```
<%@ include file="/init.jsp"%>

<jsp:useBean id="processName" class="java.util.ArrayList" scope="request" />

<aui:select id="process" name="processitems">
    <c:forEach items="${processName}" var="process">
        <aui:option value="${process}">
            ${process}
        </aui:option>
    </c:forEach>
</aui:select>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you include the declaration of core JSTl?                                                            <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>. Same thing for your aui tag

Comment: Hi @IsaacP.Liu, yes I did

Comment: How do you forward your page to the jsp? Without that your page is staying in the servlet instead of showing the content in jsp

Comment: I think that could be the issue, how do I forward it?

Comment: I tried `request.getRequestDispatcher("page2.jsp").forward(request, response);`

But I get this error: _the method getRequestDispatcher(String) is undefined for the type ActionRequest_

Comment: You need to provide the right directory for your page2.jsp, try “/page2.jsp” if same issue existed please provide your folder/file directory so we can see what is the right path for this jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

I was to use:

```
public void displayProcess(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
```

instead of

```
 public void displayProcess(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {
```

and at the bottom of my method the following:

```
renderRequest.setAttribute("process", process); 
    super.render(renderRequest, renderResponse);
```

On the jsp page, at the topmost point; receive the ArrayList that you are passing as:

```
<% ArrayList<String> process = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("process"); %>
```

.

The results are as follows:

[image: ArrayList on jsp, liferay]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a complete answer, but some steps to figure out what the problem is. I'm taking your question as well as some comments:

You're implementing a portlet action handler, from there, you won't forward/dispatch to a particular jsp: A portlet's ACTION phase is only good for changing the state, while displaying the result is part of the VIEW phase. The code that you've posted (though it's obviously simplified) looks like it rather wants to live in `doView()`.

In fact, that may be all you need: If you *just display* the portlet, *only* the VIEW phase will be triggered. Just displaying the portlet *will not* trigger the action handler, which you can validate in a debugger.

For the JSP: All you say is you "can't seem to see" any of the results. Validate where your problem is: Is the list there? Does enumerating the list work? Is your problem with the AUI taglib? You can easily check this by removing all of the other tags and rather generate pure output by removing a bit.

When you look at the output's source and any of the JSP stuff survives (e.g. the `${processName}`, or `<aui:select..>`, `<c:forEach...>`,  then you'll know that this is the root cause for "not seeing" anything. You might miss a taglib or other.

Last: I've never tried this, but `<aui:select>` is a tag that's meant to be used within a form, and I'm not sure what it does outside of a form - you may want to surround it with `<aui:form ....>` and see what happens then.